# footer's padding making it expand over its parent div width

Tags: css, opera, footer

I have a footer in my webpage with some text in it. When i try to add `padding-left` property to it, the width of the footer expands over the enclosing parent `div` element and this problem only happens with Opera and not with Chrome or Firefox or IE.. What should be done to correct it ??

CSS for footer :

```
footer {
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #3399CC;
padding-top: 12px;
padding-bottom: 12px;
width: 100%;
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can fix this problem by taking a div inside footer tag and apply padding to that div

```
<style>
footer {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #3399CC;  
    width: 100%;
    float: left;    
}
.footer {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    padding-left:10px;
}
</style>
<footer>
<div class="footer">hello this is footer</div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding an extra block level element inside of your footer, you should try the CSS3 box-sizing property with value set to border-box. The following footer definition should probably solve the problem for you:

```
footer 
{
   color: #FFFFFF;
   background-color: #3399CC;
   padding-top: 12px;
   padding-bottom: 12px;
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
   box-sizing: border-box; /* prefix accordingly */
}
```

To read a short introduction, visit the following link: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Answer (score 0):

That's a common sense. If you add "padding" and "width of 100%" you will get *that* result. Remove the "padding" or the "width of 100%" you will notice the problem no longer exist.

Add `div` tag between the parent-of-footer and the footer, and add the padding-left to that new `div`, like this:

```
<div id="parentOfFooter" style="background-color: #00ff00;">
    <div id="paddingLeftProblemSolver" style="background-color: #ff8800; padding-left:50px;">
        <div id="myfooter" style="color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #3399CC; padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 12px; width: 100%; float: left;">
            i'm a footer
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanq for your suggestion to remove the "width of 100%"... I already tried it before and it causes a problem with footer's width in opera browser[footer doesn't expand to the full width]